# Displaying DatePickerDialog in a Fragment using C# Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have an EditText and a button for the DatePickerFragment but the syntaxes are not correct of showing the DatePickerDialog and OnCreateDialog method.

This is a fragment wherein I have a TextInputLayout/EditText to be accessed on click in-order to show the DatePickerDialog. This is my code but ShowDialog() is error and is suggesting ShowsDialog() which is an error as well.

OnCreateDialog error says "CS0115: 'AddEventFragment.OnCreateDialog(int)': no suitable method found to override

```
namespace AdamsonsEDApp.Fragments
{
    public class AddEventFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment, Android.App.DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {
        private int year, month, day;
        TextInputLayout eventdatesetTextt;
        Button eventpickdateButton;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.newevent, container, false);
            this.Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            eventdatesetText = (TextInputLayout)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.eventdatesetText)
            eventpickdateButton = (Button)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.eventpickdateButton);

            eventpickdateButton.Click += EventpickdateButton_Click;
            return view;
        }

private void EventpickdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int DatePickerDialogID = 1;
            ShowDialog(DatePickerDialogID);
        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(int id)
        {
            if (id == 1)
            {
                return new Android.App.DatePickerDialog(this.Activity, this, year, month, day);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            this.year = year;
            this.month = month;
            this.day = dayOfMonth;
            eventdatesetText.EditText.Text = year + "/" + month + "/" + dayOfMonth;
        }
```

For the click event I tried:

```
private void EventpickdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int DatePickerDialogID = 1;
            **this.Activity.ShowDialog(DatePickerDialogID);**
        }
```

It has no error but it says this **this.Activity.ShowDialog(DatePickerDialogID)**; is obsolete: 'deprecated'

What is the right syntax when calling a DatePickerDialog from a Fragment? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/pickers/date-picker). I test the code official doc provided, and there are also many `obsolete` problems. However, you can add attribute and other things to fix it.

Here is the Changed code:

```
[Obsolete]
    public class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment,
                                  DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {
        // TAG can be any string of your choice.
        public static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(DatePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();

       // Initialize this value to prevent NullReferenceExceptions.
        Action<DateTime> _dateSelectedHandler = delegate { };

       public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<DateTime> onDateSelected)
        {
            DatePickerFragment frag = new DatePickerFragment();
            frag._dateSelectedHandler = onDateSelected;
            return frag;
        }

       [Obsolete]
        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                           this,
                                                           currently.Year,
                                                           currently.Month - 1,
                                                           currently.Day);
            return dialog;
        }

       public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            // Note: monthOfYear is a value between 0 and 11, not 1 and 12!
            DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
            Log.Debug(TAG, selectedDate.ToLongDateString());
            _dateSelectedHandler(selectedDate);
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        TextView _dateDisplay;
        Button _dateSelectButton;

       [Obsolete]
#pragma warning disable CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
#pragma warning restore CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            _dateDisplay = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.date_display);
            _dateSelectButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.date_select_button);
            _dateSelectButton.Click += _dateSelectButton_Click;
        }

       [Obsolete]
        private void _dateSelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DatePickerFragment frag = DatePickerFragment.NewInstance(delegate (DateTime time)
            {
                _dateDisplay.Text = time.ToLongDateString();
            });
            frag.Show(FragmentManager, DatePickerFragment.TAG);
        }

       public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
           base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Wish it could be helpful to you.